# handle Python exception/errors in PHP

Tags: php, python, error-handling

I am running some python script from within a PHP script using PHP's `exec($cmd, $output)` function.

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) states that the all output of the program is written to the `$output` array. This works fine, however, if the Python code raises an exception/error, the function seems to just return NULL, without any information on the exception.

for example:

**run_python.py**

```
print('starting python')
x = 1/0 #This will raise an error
print('complete python')
```

Running it from the **interactive PHP shell** yields the following:

```
php > $output = '';
php > $ret_val = exec('python run_python.py', $output);
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_python.py", line 2, in <module>
    x = 1/0
```

The `$output` array only contains `starting python`, and `$ret_val` contains nothing.

This is OK for the interactive shell, but I am running the code from a web interface and the error information is never displayed. Is there any way to capture that error and then display it using `echo`?

I did try [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) and [passthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php), but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect stderr to stdout

```
$ret_val = exec('python run_python.py 2>&1', $output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with: exec ( 'python run_python.py', $output,$return_var ), you'll have the error code at $return_var and the traceback at $output, and you can see it by doing

```
exec ( 'python run_python.py', $output,$return_var );
if ($return_var>0) {
    var_dump($output);
}
```